# Chrome.commands Supported Keys

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have trying to add ] key to my extension shorcut but chrome doesn't allow it.

Is there a way to override this issue? ']' key is not the supported keys according to manifest 3 yet you can navigate around tabs in chrome with: "cmd + shift + ] | [ " key binding. Is there a way I can change the navigation shortcut instead?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.